# Open a file in Windows 8 Metro App C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I have an array with **file paths** (like "C:\...") and I would like to open them with the default app, from my app. Let's say it's a list and when I click one of them, it opens.

This is the way to launch a file async:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileToLaunch);
```

It requires a `Windows.Storage.StorageFile` type of file, which has a `Path` read-only property, so I cannot set the Path. How can I open them once they're tapped/clicked?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527644/launching-a-desktop-application-with-a-metro-style-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from my link in the comments:

```
// Path to the file in the app package to launch
   string exeFile = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim\TESV.exe";

   var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(exeFile);

   if (file != null)
   {
      // Set the option to show the picker
      var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
      options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;

      // Launch the retrieved file
      bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
      if (success)
      {
         // File launched
      }
      else
      {
         // File launch failed
      }
   }
```

You can of course omit the `var options = **`-Part so the ApplicationPicker doesn't get opened

or you can use this:

```
StorageFile fileToLaunch = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(myFilePath);
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileToLaunch);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use this method 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync
on the Type `StorageFile`
This method is used to get file if you have a `path` already

Answer (score 0):

the answer is within this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec

short answer is :

```
// First, get the image file from the package's image directory.
string fileToLaunch = @"images\Icon.Targetsize-256.png";
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileToLaunch);

// Next, launch the file.
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is this:

```cs
string filePath = @"file:///C:\Somewhere\something.pdf";

    if (filePath != null)
    {
       bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(filePath));
       if (success)
       {
          // File launched
       }
       else
       {
          // File launch failed
       }
    }
```

Tha app launches it with the system default application, in this case with the Adobe Reader.