# Executing cmd commands in Windows 8 c#?

Tags: windows-8, cmd, microsoft-metro

I wish to execute a cmd command in my windows 8 Metro app. I visited many sites and I got confused. They kept saying that Windows 8 apps uses Windows RT rather than the Win32 API, as it used to before. So, can some please tell me how to execute a command in my windows 8 app?

Comment: Hope this will guide you on the issue

[Launching a Desktop Application with a Metro-style app][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527644/launching-a-desktop-application-with-a-metro-style-app

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, you can't run cmd from a metro app, as they are intended to be sandboxed from other applications, except through defined APIs like the share and search charms.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/14e2be68-ef86-4480-a3fd-6ddf7ec7d1f1

You can launch files from KnownFolders, which will open in the default application for that file-type 
though. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241801.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[BatRT](http://isys-labs.com/batrt/) allows you to run batch file commands from WinRT applications. It utilizes URI calls.