# Launch Windows Explorer from Metro style app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to download a file to the DownloadsFolder in a Windows Store App. And then I'd like to bring up a Windows Explorer open on the DownloadsFolder (actually on the folder I create in the DownloadsFolder)

But I can't figure out how to do it.

This stackoverflow question [Launching a Desktop Application with a Metro-style app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527644/launching-a-desktop-application-with-a-metro-style-app) suggests using Launcher.LaunchUriAsync. But the documentation claims:

> You cannot use this method to launch a URI in the local zone. For example, apps cannot use the file:/// protocol to access files on the local computer. Instead, you must use the Storage APIs to access files.

And indeed, I was trying to use the "file:" protocol to bring up the explorer window. When I did try this mechanism Launcher.LaunchIUriAsync fails.

If the browser can do this, why can't I?
Is there a way for me to bring up windows explorer, or is that outside the real of possibility?

Comment: This cannot be done from a Windows Store app. Browsers are special and [have permissions beyond those of standard Windows Store apps](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=243079) so don't use them as examples of what Windows Store apps can do.

Comment: You can't do this. The Windows Store Apps are sandboxed and cannot access Desktop. However, the WinRT APIs allow for navigation through files (FilePicker). Is there a reason you specifically need the explorer that cannot be achieved through WinRT APIs?

Comment: I was afraid that this was the case. What I am trying to do is make life easier for our beta testers. When we release a new version, I download the new version. I was hoping to at least pop up the explorer so they can then right click and run it in the powershell.

Comment: Duplicate for [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384778/opening-a-file-in-windows-explorer-from-a-windows-8-app/34099492#34099492](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384778/opening-a-file-in-windows-explorer-from-a-windows-8-app/34099492#34099492) See my answer there for correct approach

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can launch the Windows Explorer from metro. One thing you can use, however, is the File Picker.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-app-extension-0cb95155

Comment: As already guessed, it is impossible to launch the file protocol or explorer.exe. I however don't see how the file picker can help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to have some non-Windows Store components in your solution, there is a workaround for this. Although you can't launch a process directly, you can always run a HTTP listener inside a Windows service which listens for commands from your sandboxed Windows Store (Metro-style) app and launches Explorer (or any other process) for you. A trivial way to do this would be a Web API service inside a Windows service - just implement the GET action in your controller and have arguments for the executable to launch and optionally executable arguments as well.

This is kind of doing an end-run around the sandbox security, though, so you might want to have a tailored Web API instead which just launches a pre-packaged set of apps (like Explorer or one of your own apps).

Of course, for consumer apps this is not a good solution because you can't just install everything from the Windows Store. For LOB apps, though, it's not a bad compromise because you typically have more control over the environment. This is a good way to surface some metrics or other data into a live tile and have your desktop app launch when the tile is clicked. Whether or not this makes for a good user experience is a totally different conversation.

Answer (score 0):

[BatRT](http://isys-labs.com/batrt/) allows you to run batch file commands from WinRT applications. It utilizes URI calls. This can be used to open up applications or perform file operations.