# Open pictures library from windows 8 app (c#)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have an app that stores images in the pictures library in a subfolder.  When the pictures is saved a toast notification pops up alerting the user that the file was saved successfully.  However, I want that toast notification to be clickable, and when clicked I want it to open the pictures library to see all the saved files.

How can I launch explorer from an RT app?

Comment: that would be a rather jarring experience to open an desktop mode app from a store app. In the app spawning the toast you can use protocol activation to launch another app, but that will prompt the user for what app to run for that protocol.  Why not launch your own app and navigate to the pictures library upon clicking the toast. In general, don't you want to use every opportunity to have the use revisit YOUR app?

Comment: From a UX perspective, it is also not a good idea to notify the user that something has been successful unless the operation has a high rate of failure.  A user should be very confident that a image save operation will complete each time so you should only notify them of an error condition.  Just my opinion, but I would find a toast notification showing up every time I did something to be quite annoying.

Comment: I would also find it irritating if I got a toast notification every time I did something.  That's no the case here.  It's a download complete notification.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the sandboxing you are not allowed to do that (launch the explorer form the windows store app), the only way you could access would be by using the filepicker, and setting the display mode to thumbnails. Set folder location, viewmode and typefilter. As long as the user selects, you dont need to set this as a capability.

Filepicker:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465199.aspx

Similar question:
[Launch Windows Explorer from Metro style app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320326/launch-windows-explorer-from-metro-style-app)

General guidlines for thumbnails:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465350.aspx