# Opening a file in Windows Explorer from a Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8

I want to write a function that, quite simply minimises my Windows 8 immersive app, and opens a file in explorer - preferably if the file is in a folder with multiple files, with the file highlighted.

```
 public async void OpenFile( string filePath)
 {
     StorageFile File = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync
                              (new Uri(filePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); ;

     if (File != null)
     {
         await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(File.Path));
     }
 }
```

This code gives me a permissions error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read this article on File access and permissions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

Comment: This is can technically be done by writing a protocol handler which in turn starts Explorer.  Problem is that you cannot get it published through the store so it will be of no use to a store customer.  Scratch the idea, you cannot make this work.

Comment: @HansPassant If it can be done, I'd like to do it! I'd imagine if there was a generalised way to do this then it would be useful for quite a few internal Windows 8 applications, even if they could not make it to store :)

Comment: @Simon Hans is right that you won't be able to do this in an app published to the windows store. You can use the protocol handler route to make it work in a sideloaded LOB app, however there are costs associated with sideloading that may put it outside your reach. More details may be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx#SideloadingRequirements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> this is purely for an internal app from my point of view

This is the core problem with your intended approach.  There is no concept of an "internal app" in the Windows Store ecosystem.  The only possible way to get a Store app running on another machine is by acquiring a license key that you can only get from the Store.

This is easy to overlook when you are developing a Store app on your dev machine.  It *looks* like this license key is not required to run and debug your app.  But there actually is one, you get it when Visual Studio pesters you with a dialog once a month to re-acquire your developer license key.  This is a *temporary* key, good for only one month, and purely meant to give you enough time to get your app running solidly.  There is no mechanism to transfer that key to another machine or keep it (and the program) alive beyond the one month expiration.

You can of course still publish an internal app to the Store.  But you'll be vetted for suitability and stability by the validation procedure like any other Store app.  Not just a mechanical test like WACK performs, there are two people that will test your app before it can be published.  They will not hesitate to reject your app when you do anything to try to work around the sandbox restrictions, including the protocol handler hack.

Once approved, it will be downloadable by *any* Windows 8 user.  Including a hacker that would be interested in your internal company secrets and practices btw.  Very convenient as well, he won't have to get out of his pajamas.

A typical line-of-business app is still a desktop app for the foreseeable future.

---

This answer requires an update, there's now a mechanism to publish apps from a dedicated server.  This is called *sideloading*.  The app still requires a certificate, and it costs big bucks, but can be deployed from a private server controlled by a private company instead of the Microsoft Store server.

An overview is [available here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks for the response. You are, of course, entirely correct. My experience with Windows 8 apps thus far has been so, so frustrating. Inability to access folders, databases, or to do simple things like this make the app store, in my view, barely worth the development effort. I was carrying out this app as a proof of concept for my company prior to developing a number more apps...at this point the API is simply too restrictive and sandboxed though :(

Comment: @Hans That's not entirely true. Windows 8 does support sideloading of LOB apps on server 2012, enterprise, pro, and RT editions. See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/scd-odtsp/archive/2012/09/27/windows-8-sideloading-requirements.aspx) for more details.

Comment: You can sideload apps on Windows 8. Doing so requires you to get a sideloading key though, which costs like 3000$ for up to 100 tablets.

Comment: Ouch, the price of a number has gone up quite a bit while I wasn't looking.

Comment: @RafałSaltarski can you provide source/proof for that. From what I found (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx) & (http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation-results.aspx?Product=side) that is NOT the case. If the machines are domain joined, no side loading key needed. If they are not domain joined either a temp key (which I have personally used) or you can get keys via volume licensing which is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I recall it, MS will not allow it. 
The app should be design as if it's running in a sandbox, with limited rights.

> You can access certain file system locations, like the app install directory, app data locations, and the Downloads folder, with Windows Store apps by default. Apps can also access additional locations through the file picker, or by declaring capabilities.

I've tried the protocol handler approach, but got rejected twice :D
Even if you find a way to do this and still publish, it doesn't mean that MS won't change his mind and remove your app from the store.

Like Hans Passant was saying :

> Scratch the idea, you cannot make this work.

Comment: I don't mind about it not being accepted to be honest, this is purely for an internal app from my point of view - so it would not be listed on the Windows 8 store anyway.

Incidentally, you mention you can only access certain file locations - is that written in stone? There's no way to access the contents of any folders other than the KnownFolder location objects? That's such a pain...

Comment: "you mention you can only access certain file locations - is that written in stone?" I'm afraid it is.

If you don't mind not being listed on MS Store, then the protocol handler approach is the best way to go.
But this will imply that you will have to deliver the app update , and the all your users will be required to have a MS developer account (allowing them to install non-store apps).

PS: I am assuming that we are talking about Metro Apps(Win RT).

Answer (score 0):

There is specific API for this, nobody seems to be aware of:

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary);
```

More advanced form of this API takes options:

```
FolderLauncherOptions options = new FolderLauncherOptions();
options.ItemsToSelect.Add(file1);
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(folder, options);
```

You can also set desired view using options.DesiredRemainingView.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn889617.aspx