# Install metro application in windows 8 device

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am beginner in windows 8 metro application. I have create a simple application on visual studio 12. it is running in same machine . How can i install this application on other device running windows RT without publishing app in app store. Help me plz...Thankx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14443986/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh975357.aspx this will help you in creating package.

If you want to make a basic package, change debug mode to release mode and then follow these steps

project=> store=> create App Packages => next =>create

Comment: Sideloading must still be enabled on the target machine. And as far as I know how to do this other than getting a developer license is still a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Choose 'Store->Create App Package' from the projects context menu, then select 'no' when asked whether to create app store packages. Then copy over the generated folders and execute the included PowerShell script to install the application.
In case your project contains platform-specific code, you have to make sure it supports compilation for ARM devices, which is what Windows RT runs on.