# Cannot launch default application in a Metro app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Ok, so Windows 8 comes with a cool PDF and XLS reader app, called Reader. I have a help document that I want displayed when the user clicks the Help button inside my app. My app should launch the PDF document with whatever is the default viewer for that document type.

But it won't. There are no errors, no exceptions and setting a breakpoint reveals no information. The code I have is:

```
<Button x:Name="help" Style="{StaticResource HelpAppBarButtonStyle}" Tag="Help" Click="help_Click_1" />
```

and:

```
    private async void help_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file =
                await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"\Assets\User Guide.pdf");
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now, inside solution explorer, there are the usual files and folders. I also have an Assets folder inside the root directory, and the PDF document is located inside this root folder.

I am not sure why this isn't working, but I believe that it may have something to do with how I am pointing to the file in the above code:

`await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"\Assets\User Guide.pdf");`

How do you correctly display a document contained in the Assets folder with using the default application for that document type?

Comment: Did you looked at this information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527644/launching-a-desktop-application-with-a-metro-style-app?rq=1 before asking this question?

Comment: I have used that code, but I found it somewhere else. Didn't work (again, no exceptions were raised and no breakpoints were hit either)

Comment: You cannot "launch" a file, you would need to detect what the default program is, and launch telling said application what file to load.

Comment: That's exactly what my above code does.

Comment: you could try setting ContentType (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.contenttype) to 'application/pdf'

Comment: @Denis I think you entered the wrong link, I don't see how that's relevant. The link you sent is for Push notifications, and I cannot see anything about ContentType anywhere on that page.

Comment: Copy/paste fail :( I updated the link in the above comment. It has an example, so it should be clear how to use it.

Comment: Also, `file.ContentType` is not `get`/`set`, it's only `get`. And there's nowhere else to set `ContentType` that I am aware of.

Comment: what's the exception message?

Comment: two things to try: first, use this code to get your storage file: `var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Assets/User Guide.pdf");` Next, you may want to specify a launcher option to display the app selector, and see if it's due to a file association problem.

Comment: @jAsOn - Your code does not determine which program to launch it attempts to launch the asset in question instead doing what I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and I had to fix two issues before I got it to work:

1. Make sure the `Build Action` for the pdf file is set to `Content`. It was set to `None` in my case when I included the file in the project.
2. You need to delete the starting backslash in the file path: `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\User Guide.pdf")`.

After I changed both of the above the file opened in my default PDF viewer. But even before that an exception was raised describing what went wrong although I didn't notice it at first because of your silent try/catch code.

If it still doesn't work for you, it's probably something related to the configuration of your machine. Make sure the default viewer for pdf files is set up correctly.

Comment: Thank you @Damir; Setting the Build action to `Content` and Removing the first `\\` did the trick.