# Accessing default Media Player in Metro

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I want to know that is there is any way to access default media player in metro application. Actually, i'm developing metro application which download video and after downloading i wanted to play this video on default media player. Any comments please need help.
An alternate is to run video through launcher but the video file must be in its local storage where app exist. How i do this ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570276/cannot-launch-default-application-in-a-metro-app

Comment: It accessing file that is placed in application installed folder. In my scenario, i want to access file that is not in local folder of app, but in some where on computer. Is there is any way with out using file picker to read file from computer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use an absolute path

Comment: If you provide simple example means code snippet. It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this code, but if you try like this link, I think you could do something

[This code is from there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570276/cannot-launch-default-application-in-a-metro-app)

```
private async void help_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string file = "GamesOfThrones.mp4";
    try
    {
        StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary; //Or any other folders
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file =
            await picturesFolder.GetFileAsync(file);
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

It's an exemple with the pictures folders, get more information there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150593.aspx

Comment: Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path give bin\debug\Appx path which is local application path.

Comment: Well, sorry, I didn't see that