# Accessing the Windows registry from a XAML Start Screen application

Tags: c#, xaml, registry

I am trying to access the Windows Registry from a Windows 8 XAML Start Screen (Metric app) application from within the C# code behind and cannot see how to do it.

The XAML application uses .Net Core (v4.5), which does not include

```
using Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey;
```

where the registry functions exist.  Is there an alternate set for XAML?

I realize that the processor is AnyCPU, which is what is probably causing the problem, but I figure that there still must exist a way to access the registry.

Comment: If it's a Win 8 (Metro/Modern UI) app, then you *can't* access the registry, period. You'd have to write a regular desktop app (WPF, maybe)

Comment: I have a regular desktop winforms application that a user installs, but also wanted a Metro application component, which amongst other things allows the user to start the desktop app.  The problem that I see is how to know where the application got installed, if I cannot access the registry.  Also, I do not see System.Data.*, which means that how do I access (and find) my database file.

Comment: You might want to check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527644/launching-a-desktop-application-with-a-metro-style-app), but I'm not entirely sure how helpful it's going to be. Metro apps are heavily sandboxed, so there's only as much as you can do. There are some hacky ways to get around some of those limitations, but still...

Comment: That thread was quite interesting.  That was one problem, namely how to launch my desktop application from Metro. The problem now is that a user can install my application anywhere, not necessarily the default.  I almost never install apps to the default location.  Using the registry was my idea on this topic.