# Questions about Windows App (Metro) Tiles/Icons for desktop applications

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have an application written in VB.NET that I want to move to Win10.  It will always be a desktop application, however I would like it to have a start icon / tile in Win 10.  Looking around [I found this exact question](https://superuser.com/questions/493665/how-to-add-a-metro-looking-tile-for-a-desktop-application) which suggests to create a Metro App (now I believe called Windows App) which launches the desktop app.  This is [also discussed in this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527644/launching-a-desktop-application-with-a-metro-style-app) So the questions;

1. These threads are a little old is the best way in Win10 to give a desktop app a Windows App Tile by using a Windows App as the Launcher for the desktop app?
2. It appears that in Win10 Microsoft has now allowed non-store apps to be installed in Update Security > SideloadApps.  This needs to be enabled to install the App, but does this need to be always enabled.  For example what happens after install if the user turns it off, will the app then not start?
   For example I see [in this link that there are 2 Registry keys to change](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/5-steps-to-an-ideal-windows-10-app-development-environment/), basically AllowAllTrustedApps and AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense.  Is it possible for my desktop installer to change these keys, install the Windows App (and everything else) and then change the keys back again?
3. Uninstalling? If I created a Windows App which only launched my desktop app then there is a possibility that the user uninstalls or deletes the Windows App, meaning my desktop app would be orphaned and lost.  Any suggestion on solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I think what you need is [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop). There is no need to use a Windows App as the Launcher for the desktop app.

You can try with [Desktop App Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter), with this you can bring your existing desktop apps written for .NET 4.6.1 or Win32 to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP).

And after converting, you can replace the Assets generated by Desktop App Converter (DAC) automatically to provide custom Tiles/Icons. For more, you can refer to [Manually convert your app to UWP using the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The only thing i dont want or cannot do is convert it.  I just want it to look like an app.

Comment: @darbid I'd also think Desktop Bridge is the right way to go. Why you don't want or can't do it?

Comment: The desktop app uses Internet Explorer 11\ MSHTM and various other COM libraries such as Office 2010. The dasktop app also exposes its own methods to COM.

Comment: Based on my general question and now what I have read on the Bridge software this is the answer.  It means I have a 1000 more questions, but as far as this question is concerned, Thank you.